Does Vercel not recognise the correct src?
I have deployed my SvelteKit project using Vercel. Everything works fine except for the attribute "src" in "app.html". I have used this line <script type="module" src="js/dataReader.js"></script> to insert my transcript files. This works fine when using localhost to open the website, however, with Vercel it doesn't seem to work. The error message " basketball-test-2.vercel.app/:46
GET https://basketball-test-2.vercel.app/js/dataReader.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) " appears, which suggest that the vercel is looking for a website instead of a file path.
I have tried to copy everything from the file "dataReader.js" into "app.html" and it works, but it isn't a clean way to deal with my problem. So I wanted to know if there is a better way.

Try moving dataReader.js to static/js/dataReader.js from the root folder if it's a static asset.

If you want code to always run, put it in a layout.
The app.html is barely processed at all and you generally should not mess with it.
